# HMAC API exposed via public site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hmac, antiforgerytoken

What steps can I take to prevent unauthorised access to our API (if indeed any are required)?

**Background**

The diagram below illustrates a microsite we're implementing, and an HMAC API we're providing (for several purposes) which returns commercially sensitive data to authenticated consumers.  The arrows represent intended (green) and unintended (red) communication.

[image: component diagram]

The HMAC API is intended for address autocompletion.  There is no login for the microsite.  The page has an address input.  To enable autocomplete the page makes an AJAX GET call to the controller after each keystroke.  For each AJAX GET call, the controller constructs the HMAC and makes a request to the HMAC API.

**The problem**

I can't see anything currently preventing consumption of the AJAX GET method.

**Considerations**

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473856/asp-net-mvc-csrf-on-a-get-request) that AnitForgeryTokens aren't useful on GET methods, but that you can get around this by turning it into a POST.  That sounds a bit ugly, but since this is only a microsite (i.e. we're throwing it away after a month or so) I'm quite prepared to put up with ugly security.

Seven years on from that, is that still the best way?

Comment: @Amy, I don't think the AJAX call could be authenticated since there's no page authentication. But maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Amy, wouldn't the token have to be embedded in the page?  And therefore could be stolen?

Comment: @Amy - cookie/embedded makes no difference because the attacker can just request our page, get the token, and attach/embed it with his unintended request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> prevent unauthorised access to a method on an unauthenticated controller

If you don't have any authentication and authorization (*"unauthenticated controller"*) then there can be no such thing as an unauthorized access: i.e. every access is allowed. And, what does not exist cannot be prevented.

If you could defined what unauthorized access means in your use case you might be able to add some authorization which prevents it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using a term which has a technical connotation, but I'm using it in its more general sense. By "unauthorised" I mean any requests originated from outside the microsite.

Comment: @OutstandingBill: what exactly is "outside" and "inside"? If "inside" is a specific range of IP addresses from clients you could limit access by IP. If "inside" means that the browser first visited the microsite and then visited the API then you have to include a proof for this, for example some time limited token signed by the microsite which can be verified by the API.

Comment: We don't know the IP addresses of the intended users. The user doesn't visit the API, they visit the controller (which one could argue is effectively an API, but I'm trying to be consistent with my diagram). Regardless, having been served by the controller, the page could contain a limited-lifetime token. The token could be "stolen" though and used in unauthorised calls (in the general sense).

Comment: @OutstandingBill: if the access to the API follows immediately the visit of the microsite than the token can have a very short lifetime. If you also use HTTPS to protect the transport stealing and using of the token within the lifetime gets unlikely.

Comment: The nature of the form means they might take a while between requesting it and submitting, and the autocomplete could happen any time between.

Comment: I'm getting the general impression that securing this resource is theoretically impossible (as your answer says: "there can be no such thing as an unauthorized access") given the implementation constraints, so I need to consider ways (such as those you've outlined) to minimise the risk.