# Trigger an action method from View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an action method like this

```
  [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin()
        {
            string provider = "";
            string returnUrl = null;
            if (returnUrl.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            {
                returnUrl = Request.RawUrl;
            }

            // Request a redirect to the external login provider
            return new ChallengeResult(provider,
                Url.SurfaceAction<UmbracoIdentityAccountController>("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }
```

I want to trigger this method when a particular view is rendered.
I tried some thing like this

```
  @Html.Action("ExternalLogin", "UmbracoIdentityAccount");
```

But this throws an error

```
A public action method 'ExternalLogin' was not found on controller
```

Can anyone please point out what is the right approach to do this?

Comment: The `@Html.Action()` uses the `[HttpGet]` method. But ASP.NET MVC `AntiForgeryToken`  works through `POST`. See [ASP.NET MVC - CSRF on a GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35473856/6630084). Therefore, you have two attributes applied to the method that conflict with the `@Html.Action()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC `AntiForgeryToken` works through HTTP PUT, by design.

The `@Html.Action()` uses `[HttpGet]` method not the `[HttpPost]` as the `ExternalLogin` is defined.

Therefore, the simpler way is to change the action method definition to:

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin()
{
    ...
}
```